# Authorize.net - Customer ID (working with CIM)

Tags: payment-processor, authorize.net

We are changing to authorize.net as payment processor.  Everything is working fine. We have the Customer Information Manager (CIM) in  Authorize.net turned on.  When we do a recurring billing Civi creates a  customer record in authorize.net and adds the CiviCRM Internal Contact ID as the authorize.net Customer ID.  However, on standard transactions Civi does not seem to interact with the authorize.net CIM.

Can Civi work with the authorize.net CIM for standard transactions and pass the customer ID?

We are on Civi 4.6 but will upgrade to 4.7 within 2 months. On Drupal 7.